# How to integrate an exe file and 2 dll files into my visual basic program?

Tags: vb.net, cmd, integration

I am writing a visual basic GUI program with a form. Now my program makes use of an executable(command line program) file called adb.exe. This file depends on 2 dll files. I want to integrate these 3 files into my program so that I can execute commands from the adb.exe file. How can I do this? I need just the integration part. I know how to execution of commands part. I tried putting the 3 files into my project in visual studio but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to use them as resources? Maybe as a code folder or put them in the bin file.

Comment: You can't build those files into your EXE and be able to run them. I think you just want them to be part of your installation, not your program.

Comment: @Eminem I have used them as resources. But it doesn't work. How do I put them in a bin file?

Comment: @Steve Kinda. I want to use the adb.exe file. Like my program should be able to execute this command via command prompt "adb devices -l" which will list all the devices. So it has to have access to this file and its dependencies. Maybe it can be embedded in the program or maybe it can copy the 3 files(adb.exe and the other 2 dll files) into a temporary folder every time I open my program and execute the adb.exe file from the temporary folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them as resources, and set them as embedded resources.
When you need them you can extract them with a similar code:

```
Dim Resourcename() As Byte = My.Resources.yourresourcename
Dim FileN As New System.IO.FileStream("path to the wished location and filename", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
Dim BW As New System.IO.BinaryWriter(FileN)
BW.write(Resourcename)
BW.Close()
FileN.Close()
```

Comment: Hi @andrejke thanks. Tried that. But when I try directly opening my exe file the files get created but my exe application does not show on the screen. If I run it through Visual Studio it shows up on the screen. But not when I run the exe directly.

Comment: It was my fault. I forgot to change the working directory. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Add them to your application's [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wkcc526(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I have done that. But then how to I call out shell commands from the file (adb.exe) that I added to resources?

Answer (score 0):

Under the project tab, select properties.
From the properties menu, select the reference tab, and set 'copy local' to true for all of them.

Now 'publish' the program and all the references will be included with the build and referenced correctly.

Comment: Thanks. But firstly how do I add my own 3 files as references. 1 is an application file and the other 2 are dll files.